# jquery place cursor in fadein element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I place the cursor inside an element that is called using another function and it fades in? This is the function I have now:

```
 function ajax_cart() {
   var url = 'shoppingcart.php';    
   jQuery("#carttopcontainer").load(url);
   jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
   jQuery("#carttopcontainer").fadeIn(400);
   jQuery('#carttopcontainer').hoverIntent({
     over: startHover,
     out: endHover,
     timeout: 1000
    });
 }
```

The `#carttopcontainer` div is a small popup that shows the cart div container after an item was added using ajax post. I want to put the mouse cursor anywhere inside that div after if fades in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my question was probably incorrect and hard to understand, but here's what I was trying to do:
I have a div that shows up and then I needed to hide it after a few seconds, but only if the mouse is not over that div. If mouse gets over that div, it should remain visible. Also, if the mouse leaves and returns fast, it might have been accidental so the div should still be visible. Here's how I accomplished it:

```
$("#carttopcontainer").delay(3000).animate({height:"hide",opacity:"hide"}, 2000).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({height:"275px",opacity:1}, 200)}).mouseleave(function() {$(this).animate({height:"hide",opacity:"hide"}, 2000)});
```

I'm pretty sure there are some better solutions, but this one works for me so I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can not move the user's cursor with JavaScript. If you want to focus an element, you can use [`element.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.focus)

Comment: Honestly, I don't seem to understand what I get with focus(). I'm basically trying to get the hoverIntent to kick in. The idea is that the cart div shows up and stays open for a second or two and then fades out. I've added hoverIntent so when you put your cursor over the #carttopcontainer and move it out, the div fades out after a second. Now I need to get the same thing to happen even if the mouse isn't inside that div, but it must NOT happen while the mouse is there... I hope it makes sense. :)

Comment: You can not get the mouse to move. You can try to trigger a mouseover event with jQuery [`element.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), but wouldn't it be easier to call the code that makes it seem like it is hovered?

Comment: Hm... I don't think any code that makes it seem like it's hovered would help because I want the div to hide if mouse out, but keep visible while mouseover... Is there an alternative solution to fadeIn that div and set a timer to fadeOut, but reset the timer if mouseover?